# Как убрать отступы от текста в виджете QLabel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qlayout, qlabel

Помогите пожалуйста, я создаю текст через `QLabel`, а он создает огромные рамки, я подсветил их ярко-зелёным цветом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это решить?

---

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from quizz_window import QuizzWindow

app = QApplication([])

quizz_window = QuizzWindow()
quizz_window.resize(480,320)
quizz_window.show()
app.exec()
```

**quizz_window.py**:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QGroupBox,
    QRadioButton, QSpinBox, QLabel
)

class QuizzWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        btn_menu = QPushButton("Меню")
        wat = QPushButton("Отдохнуть")
        mins = QSpinBox()
        mintext = QLabel("Минут")
        mintext.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgreen")
        #mintext.resize(50, 50)
        question = QLabel("2+2=")

        RadioButtons = QGroupBox("Варианты ответов")
        rbtn1 = QRadioButton('1')
        rbtn2 = QRadioButton('2')
        rbtn3 = QRadioButton('3')
        rbtn4 = QRadioButton('4')

        rbtn_main_line = QVBoxLayout()
        rbtn_top_horizontal = QHBoxLayout()
        rbtn_down_horizontal = QHBoxLayout()
        rbtn_main_line.addLayout(rbtn_top_horizontal)
        rbtn_main_line.addLayout(rbtn_down_horizontal)
        
        rbtn_top_horizontal.addWidget(rbtn1)
        rbtn_top_horizontal.addWidget(rbtn2)

        rbtn_down_horizontal.addWidget(rbtn3)
        rbtn_down_horizontal.addWidget(rbtn4)
        
        RadioButtons.setLayout(rbtn_main_line)

        main_lin = QVBoxLayout()
        uphline = QHBoxLayout()
        downupline = QHBoxLayout()
        horizontal_line = QHBoxLayout()

        main_lin.addLayout(uphline)

        uphline.addWidget(btn_menu, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
        uphline.addWidget(wat, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight, stretch=2)
        uphline.addWidget(mins, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight)
        uphline.addWidget(mintext, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight)

        #main_lin.addLayout(downupline)
        #downupline.addWidget(question, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

        main_lin.addWidget(RadioButtons)
        main_lin.addLayout(horizontal_line)
    
        self.setLayout(main_lin)
        self.show()
```

Comment: myay, все очень сложно, попробуйте как-то показать и объяснить на изображении что вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 0):

Я увидел вашу задачу так:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QGroupBox,
    QRadioButton, QSpinBox, QLabel, QApplication, QFrame, 
    QGridLayout, QButtonGroup
)


#from 'Имя второго файла' import QuizzWindow
class QuizzWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        self.frame_top = QFrame()
        btn_menu = QPushButton("Меню")
        wat = QPushButton("Отдохнуть")
        mins = QSpinBox()
        mintext = QLabel("Минут")
        mintext.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgreen")
        layout_frame_top = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_top)
        layout_frame_top.addWidget(btn_menu)
        layout_frame_top.addStretch(1)
        layout_frame_top.addWidget(wat)
        layout_frame_top.addWidget(mins)
        layout_frame_top.addWidget(mintext)

        self.question = QLabel("2 + 2 = ?", alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.question.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgreen; font-size: 17px;")
        downupline = QHBoxLayout()
        downupline.addWidget(self.question)        

        self.groupBox = QGroupBox("Варианты ответов") 
        layout_bottom = QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        rbtn1 = QRadioButton('1')
        rbtn2 = QRadioButton('2')
        rbtn3 = QRadioButton('3')
        rbtn4 = QRadioButton('4')
        layout_bottom.addWidget(rbtn1, 1, 1)
        layout_bottom.addWidget(rbtn2, 1, 2)
        layout_bottom.addWidget(rbtn3, 2, 1)
        layout_bottom.addWidget(rbtn4, 2, 2)
        layout_bottom.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        layout_bottom.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        layout_bottom.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
        layout_bottom.setColumnStretch(3, 1)
        # это вам бонусом
        button_group = QButtonGroup(self)
        button_group.buttonClicked.connect(lambda rb: print(f'rb={rb.text()}'))
        button_group.addButton(rbtn1)
        button_group.addButton(rbtn2)
        button_group.addButton(rbtn3)
        button_group.addButton(rbtn4)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.frame_top, 
            stretch=0, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.question, stretch=1)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    quizz_window = QuizzWindow()
    quizz_window.setWindowTitle("Example")
    quizz_window.resize(480, 320)
    quizz_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @myay что не так?